# How to include a jar file in classpath and run another jar in linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, classpath

I am trying to run a jar file on Linux but it requires another jar file to run. To be specific I have added ojdbc8 separately in Eclipse as I am unable to add it in pom.xml. In Eclipse it works fine but in Linux when I try to run the command

```
java -cp "/home/eim_master/EirRefresh/lib/ojdbc8.jar" -jar EirRefresh-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

even after including ojdbc8 jar it still fails throwing

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I need to run the main class and start the spring boot application

Answer (score 0):

The `-cp` option is for a directory.
Try `java -cp "/home/eim_master/EirRefresh/lib/" -jar EirRefresh-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Thanks for the solution but just tried this still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

java -cp "target/EirRefresh-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:lib/ojdbc8.jar" org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher